# How to let users choose to hide fields in their profile?

Tags: users

Is there a way to allow users to choose to hide certain fields in their profile?

For example if building a job site, a user might choose to hide their name from others. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a checkbox field just below the field you want to hide on user profile page.
2. Now override the settings in template file.

Please follow the link [allow users to choose whether certain profile fields are visible or hidden](https://www.drupal.org/node/45882) for detailed steps.

Also you can try out [Profile2 Privacy](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_privacy) module.

> This module extends Profile 2 by allowing administrators to create
>   privacy levels as predefined groups or sets of profile fields on a per
>   role basis. Users can then select from among the privacy levels to
>   apply access control to their profile.